# Difference between "could do" and "could have done"

Tags: meaning-in-context, modal-verbs

I tried to find the difference between following two sentences:

> I ***could do*** it.

> I ***could have done*** it.

I am still confused between these two sentences. Please let me know what is the difference between them in context.

Comment: [Related](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61226/could-have-vs-could):

Answer (score 2):

**John**: We are having a party tomorrow. I need someone to cook the fish.

**Alice**: I could do it.

That is, in the future, Alice can cook the fish.

---

**John**: The party was a disaster. No-one knew how to cook the fish.

**Alice**: I could have done it.

That is, in the past, Alice could have cooked the fish.

---

*Compare to:*

**John**: We are hungry. We need someone to cook the fish.

**Alice**: I can do it.

That is, in the present, Alice can cook the fish.